# References on quadrature of $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \exp(-x^a) dx$

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, approximate-integration, quadrature

I am aware of Hermite-Gaussian quadrature techniques for integrals of the form
$$
\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \exp(-x^2) dx
$$
However, am I looking for references on quadrature where the exponent is more generally $a \in (0, 2]$.

My understanding is that Hermite polynomials are applied in the special case above because they make for an orthogonal system with respect to $\exp(-x^2)$. I would therefore assume that a different kind of polynomials must be used when $a \neq 2$, but it is unclear to me exactly how one would find such polynomials.

Comment: The procedure is still the same as the Gauss-Hermite case, you just have to actually do it again in order to get the weights and nodes.

Comment: @Ian see my edit

Comment: There's a standard procedure for constructing the relevant orthogonal polynomials for a given sufficiently nice weight function. You can look it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: The procedure is more or less Gram-Schmidt: start with $p_0(x)=1$, normalize it to $q_0(x)$, set $p_1(x)=xq_0(x)$, project out $q_0$ and normalize to get $q_1(x)$. Finally, given $q_0,\dots,q_k$, construct $q_{k+1}$ by setting $p_{k+1}(x)=xq_k(x)$, projecting out $q_k$ and $q_{k-1}$, and normalizing. Proceeding this way, instead of simply taking $p_k=x^k$, allows you to avoid full Gram-Schmidt, which saves computation time and improves numerical stability.

Comment: For $a\in\left(0,2\right]$, can you just perform a change of variable, i.e., by letting $y=x^{a/2}$ and rewriting the integral as $\int_{\left[0,\infty\right]}g(y)e^{-y^2}{\rm d}y$ for some $g$?

Comment: @hypernova hmm that seems to be possible, yes